# Why is a 32bit OS limited to 4 GigaBytes of RAM?

Tags: memory, 32bit-64bit, cpu-architecture

What I don't understand is where the 4 GigaBytes comes from.

Most of the articles I read say that 2^32bits = 4 GigaBytes, but this doesn't seem correct given that 8 bits = 1 byte.

For a 32 **bit** OS:
2^32 = 4,294,967,295 **bits** = 4.2 Giga **bits** = 536870911.875 **bytes** = 0.4999999998836 Giga **bytes**

Can someone please enlighten me as to what I'm missing?

Comment: Let me Stackoverflow that for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119278/why-does-a-32-bit-os-support-4-gb-of-ram

Comment: It's the address space. Unless you resort to Kludges, that's what is directly addressable by the processor and therefore the OS written for that processor. Get a 64 bit OS and the next level processor quits having to emulate the previous version. This has been answered many times, many many times. No, we aren't stupid and we didn't get the math wrong. MEGO

Answer (score 2):

It's not "2^32 *bits* = 4 GigaBytes", it's "2^32 *bytes* = 4 GigaBytes". A CPU doesn't handle memory in *bits*, it handles memory in *bytes* (*).

In order to use memory, a CPU needs to be able to address it; the address of a byte in memory is a 32-bit number which acts as an index in the computer's RAM. Thus, a 32-bit CPU is able to address at most 2^32 *bytes*, i.e. 4 GB.

For more details, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_address).

(*) Usually.

Comment: "*Thus, a 32-bit CPU is able to address at most 2^32 bytes, i.e. 4 GB.*" This is completely untrue. 32-bit CPUs have been handling more than 4GB of RAM for about 20 years now. In the x86 lineup, the Pentium Pro, released in 1995, was a 32-bit CPU that could address up to 64GB of memory. The 4GB limit is a *software* limitations of some 32-bit operating systems, not a hardware limitation of 32-bit CPUs.

Comment: I know there is a little more than "4 GB is the roof limit". I was just trying to keep it simple so not to confuse the OP even more.

Comment: It is often challenging to keep something simple without saying things that are actually false. But I think it's important.